# How to run pop up an dialog on background when the data matches within my code

Tags: android

I have a `Date` array which stored dates and time in its respective positions in my app like:

```
private Date    m_DateTimeArray[];

m_DateTimeArray = new Date[Utilities.DATE_TIME_MAX_COUNT];

m_DateTimeArray[0] = 1-july-2012 12:30:00
m_DateTimeArray[1] = 1-july-2012 01:00:00
m_DateTimeArray[2] = 1-july-2012 02:30:00
m_DateTimeArray[3] = 1-july-2012 03:15:00
m_DateTimeArray[4] = 1-july-2012 04:20:00
m_DateTimeArray[5] = 1-july-2012 05:00:00
m_DateTimeArray[6] = 1-july-2012 06:30:00
```

Now I exit my app, so now on the background what I want is, whenever my device current date matches this date stored in an array, it pops up one dialog with some information, similarly whenever my current date matches next date store in an array it again pop up a dialog. So this whole process should run whether my app is in a running state or not in a running state. So how that can be done. I go through many examples like `AlarmManager`, `IntetService`, Service, But not able to get the result that I want. So if anyone works on such issue, please help me to solve this out.

**Code of my main Activity**

```
public class AndroidAlarmService extends Activity 
{
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startalarm);
    Button buttonCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelalarm);

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmService.this, MyAlarmService.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

            Toast.makeText(AndroidAlarmService.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }});

    buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            
            // Tell the user about what we did.
            Toast.makeText(AndroidAlarmService.this, "Cancel!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }});

}
}
```

**Code in my alarm service**

```
public class MyAlarmService extends IntentService 
{   
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();
}

public MyAlarmService() 
{
    super("MyAlarmService");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}
            
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: Check the Url :: http://alchemiaandroid.altervista.org/AlarmManagerTutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways like Making one BroadCast Receiver with the Action TIME_TICK and Using AlarmManager, But as reading your requirement there is only one preffered way for you is to **use AlarmManager**.

Whenever the data in the DATE Array generated you need to set one Alarm for each of the elements of the Array.

I am sure you have tried many Examples available on net for the same, Then I tell you to use them again [EXAMPLE](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html) you will use this example as it is, you will just have to change one thing in the code like where they haved added `cal.add(Seconds,10);` there *instead of it* you will have to **add the difference of your current time and date array element time**.

The rest of the code from example will remain as it is.

EDIT Trying To Write Code

```
    for(int i=0;i<dateArray.length();i++)
    {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmService.this, MyAlarmService.class); 
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, myIntent, 0); 

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
    calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, diff(dateArray[i])); 
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent); 

    Toast.makeText(AndroidAlarmService.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }

    long diff(Date date) {
        long difference = 0;
        try {

            // set current time
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            difference = date.getTime() - c.getTimeInMillis();
            if (difference < 0) {
                difference = difference * -1;
                difference = 86400000 - difference;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return difference;
    }
```

Comment: Just Look at my edited answer. I used this code but it show alarm for only one dates only..But i want to show alarm for all my dates that are stored in an array, whenever they match with current date. Can u please modified my code and tell me how that be done.

Comment: One more thing u said that i have to add the difference of your current time and date array element time. But if the user set the alarm time of next day like 3-july-2012 8:30:00, the what happen, the alarm will pop up today only because we are only find the time  difference.

Comment: Will surely try and modify the code for you,and the time diff you need to add in the current date so the alarm will trigger only when the time comes

Comment: So can you please edited the code to let me know what actually i have to do..I am stuck in this topic.

Comment: Check the Edited Answer, You need to do something that way @Anshuman

Comment: It work, but only for one date, i mean to say suppose my current date is 2-july-2012 4:00:00, In my array suppose i have two dates 2-july-2012 4:03:00 and 2-july-2012 4:05:00. Now it popup for first date in an array, but not for 2nd date of an array

Comment: Debug your code and check 2 things : how many times it goes into loop to set alarm and check what is return value of diff() and Also, Change 0,0 from pending intent to `i`

Comment: yeh its working..thanks a lot, i  Change 0,0 from pending intent to i..its work like a charm...

Comment: What actually this pending intent do.

Comment: Can u please explain, what actually happen in diff() method and why we 86400000 to find a difference

Comment: that's total number of miliseconds of 24hr a Day..if and only if the diff is in minus..means the alarm time is of prev time then current..then firstly we change it positive by * -1 and then substract from 86400000 to get the exact new time to play alarm..

Comment: Ok i understand..one more thing i want to clear..Actually in my app i have some notes and in that note i set alarm. So when the alarm time matches the device time i am displaying an dialog with that notes EveryThing works fine, But if i set same alarm time in two notes then the dialog popup only once.

Comment: Hey in ur diff method u specify that when alarm time is of previous time then current time then also the alarm pop-up, but nothing pop-up

Comment: it will pop-up when the time comes in future again..mean if you have set for 7-july then it will pop-up on next 7th july

Comment: Today i found one issue in the code..when user set alarm for next month or previous month means suppose current date is 9-july-2012 11:30 and if the user set alarm date as 10-aug-2012 12:30 or 8-june-2012, then on exit of app the alarm pop-up. Which is wrong.So how can i solve this issue